# Simple TypeScript spread not working?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm a TypeScript newbie, so please bear with me if I've made a mistake.

According to [this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/spread-operator.html), an online TypeScript guide, the following TypeSript is valid:

```
function foo(x, y, z) { }
var args = [0, 1, 2];
foo(...args);
```

Instead, when I run `tsc *.ts --watch --target ES6` to compile my TypeScript, I get `error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

Shouldn't this work just fine? It's quite a basic task, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of `tsc` are you using?

Comment: It's a known Typescript issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4130

Answer (score -3):

You can try this code  [there](https://jsfiddle.net/3sLfw4mz/2/)

```js
function foo(x:number, y:number, z:number):void {
 console.log(x,y,z);
}
let args:number[] = [0, 1, 2];
foo(...args);
```

**strong text**